# initialize javascript in php script for a contact form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Hi there working on a simple contact form.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required><br />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Mail" required><br />
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Nachricht" required></textarea><br />
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

with a simple php mailer

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="Von: $name \n Nachricht: $message" ;
$recipient = "mail@mail.com";
$subject = "$betreff";
$mailheader = "Von: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" //need to be removed;
?>
```

Im using a simple javascript for changing the button to 'sending'

```
var send = document.getElementById('submit');
    if(send) {
        send.onclick = function () {
            this.innerHTML = 'sending';
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to change the button innerhtml to `sent` after the php script is successfully done? Also how can I avoid the redirection to the mail.php?

First it should show the `send`. After clicking `sending` should appear and when the mail.php is dont `sent` should appear in the button.

Any ideas or suggestions?

best regards
dennym

Edit: Further Progress and solution [error on contact form submit via jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769651/error-on-contact-form-submit-via-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the button innerhtml to sent after the php
>   script is successfully done?

If you reload the same template you can have the button rendered as `sent`.  You have to track the state of the form though on the backend.  YOu could change your form to submit through javascript using ajax.  After a successful response is received you can change the innerHTML.

> Also how can I avoid the redirection to the mail.php?

Don't submit the form.  Use javascript to collect values and make an ajax request.

Comment: changed to new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769651/error-on-contact-form-submit-via-jquery-ajax for better overview

Answer (score 0):

You should use an XHR (AJAX) request.

Rather than writing plain javascript like in your example, you'll get further faster with a javascript framework such as jQuery.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('form#formId').submit(function(){

    //set submit label to sending
    $('form#formId #submit').html('sending');

    $.post('mail.php', function(){
        //set submit label to sent
        $('form#formId #submit').html('sent');
    });

    //returning false to prevent native submission of form.
    return false;

});
```

You'll need to give your form an ID attribute so that you can selectively select it.