# error on contact form submit via jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767317/initialize-javascript-in-php-script-for-a-contact-form) i had to rewrite my contact form script.
The goal is to to have a send button labeled `send`. After clickick it should show `sending` till the php script is done. When its done it should show `sent`.

Thats my simple form:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="mail.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required><br />
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Mail" required><br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Nachricht" required></textarea><br />
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Here is the jquery script for the label changing and the ajax submit.

```
<script>
            $( init );
            function init() {
                $('#contactForm').submit( submitForm );
            }
            function submitForm() {
                var contactForm = $(this);
                if ( !$('#name').val() || !$('#email').val() || !$('#message').val() ) {
                    $('#submit').html('error');
                } else {
                    $('#submit').html('sending');
                    $.ajax( {
                      url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
                      type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
                      data: contactForm.serialize(),
                      success: submitFinished
                    } );
                }
                return false;
            }
            function submitFinished( response ) {
                response = $.trim( response );
                if ( response == "success" ) {
                    $('#submit').HTML = ('sent');
                } else {
                  $('#submit').html('error');
                }
            }
        </script>
```

the mail.php:

```
<?php 

define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Doe" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "john@doe.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Subject" );

$success = false;

$name = isset( $_POST['name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['name'] ) : "";
$email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";
$message = isset( $_POST['message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['message'] ) : "";

if ( $name && $email && $message ) {
  $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
  $headers = "Von: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">";
  $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
}

if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $success ? "success" : "error";
} else {
 //add html for javascript off user
}
?>
```

Its submits correct and i get the mail but i doesnt change the label to `sent`.Its stuck at `sending`. 
Any idea or suggestions whats wrong with my code?

best regards
dennym

Comment: What is the output when you view the request in Firebug or Dev Tools or whatever?

Comment: Try making the HTML be html

Comment: Also try and alert for the response to make sure that it says success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
$('#submit').HTML = ('sent');
```

Change that to:

```
$('#submit').html('sent');
```

Comment: -.- this must be happen because of some autocomplete, dont know, but this helped

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#submit').HTML = ('sent');
```

should be

```
$('#submit').html('sent');
```

like you have everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change

```
$('#submit').HTML = ('sent');
```

to:

```
$('#submit').html('sent');
```

in your function `submitFinished()`;